# Cannot access element in tuple

Tags: python

I am writing a function that takes in a list of tuples and calculates grades. The problem is only the work for the first element is returned.

Each tuple contains a string for name and four integers for three midterms and a final. The midterms are each worth 20% of the final grade. The final is worth 40% of the final grade.

The function is supposed to return a dictionary containing names and final grades. Right now, only the values for the first element in the tuple are added to the dictionary.

Example: tuple1 produces an incorrect result of {'Tim Roe': 88}

tuple1 = [("Tim Roe", 56, 81, 98, 93), ("Joe Adams", 90, 100, 89, 78), ("Sally Lee", 77, 88, 67, 90)]

```
def getGrades(tuples):
    for tup in tuples:
        (name, midterm1, midterm2, midterm3, final) = tup

        # get average of midterm grades
        average_midterm = (midterm1 + midterm2 + midterm3) / 3.0

        # replace if average is better
        if average_midterm > midterm1:
            midterm1 = average_midterm

        if average_midterm > midterm2:
            midterm2 = average_midterm

        if average_midterm > midterm3:
            midterm3 = average_midterm

        # weight grades
        midterm1_weight = midterm1 * 0.20
        midterm2_weight = midterm2 * 0.20
        midterm3_weight = midterm3 * 0.20
        final_weight = final * 0.40

        # calculate grade
        grade = midterm1_weight + midterm2_weight + midterm3_weight + final_weight
        grade = math.floor(grade)

        grade_dict = dict()
        grade_dict[name] = grade
        return grade_dict ----> returns name and grade for first tuple only
```

Comment: Your return statement is inside the loop

Comment: What is your function *supposed to do*. Please always provide a complete description of what's going on.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez is correct. You need to move the return statement four spaces (or one tab character) to the left.

Comment: @NicholasHunter: More than that though; they're making the `dict` fresh on every pass, they need to move it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the dictionary before you enter the loop and you need to execute the return statement after you exit the loop.

```
def getGrades(tuples):

    grade_dict = dict()

    for tup in tuples:
        (name, midterm1, midterm2, midterm3, final) = tup

        # get average of midterm grades
        average_midterm = (midterm1 + midterm2 + midterm3) / 3.0

        # replace if average is better
        if average_midterm > midterm1:
            midterm1 = average_midterm

        if average_midterm > midterm2:
            midterm2 = average_midterm

        if average_midterm > midterm3:
            midterm3 = average_midterm

        # weight grades
        midterm1_weight = midterm1 * 0.20
        midterm2_weight = midterm2 * 0.20
        midterm3_weight = midterm3 * 0.20
        final_weight = final * 0.40

        # calculate grade
        grade = midterm1_weight + midterm2_weight + midterm3_weight + final_weight
        grade = math.floor(grade)

        grade_dict[name] = grade

    return grade_dict
```

Answer (score -2):

Once a tuple is created, you cannot change its values. Tuples are unchangeable, or immutable as it also is called. But there is a workaround. You can convert the tuple into a list, change the list, and convert the list back into a tuple.

```py
#Initilizing
age = 67
tuple = (num1, num2, num3)

# Using
age = tuple[0] # You can Access It
tuple[0] = age # You cannot Change It
```

Comment: This is true, but this doesn't have anything to do with the OP's question... nowhere do they try to mutate a tuple